# Why I can not override method using implementation of class as parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have simple abstract structure

```
public abstract class Data<A extends Serializable> {

}
```

and then String implementation of this class

```
public class StringData extends Data<String> {

}
```

then I have Interface:

```
public interface Testicek<A extends Serializable> {

    public abstract Data<A> test(Data<A> bla);

}
```

and now I want to create class which implement this interface:

```
public class TesticekImpl implements Testicek<String> {


    // OK
    @Override
    public StringData test(Data<String> bla) {
        return null;
    }

    // compilation error
    //@Override
    //public StringData test(StringData bla) {
    //    return null;
    //}

}
```

Why I can not use my StringData class as parameter and it only works in return type ? Signatures of return type and parameter are same.

Comment: Because the fact that you implement Testicek<String> mandates that you must accept *any* object of type Data<String>. StringData is merely *one* of the illimited number of subtypes of Data<String>. That's not enough. You must accept all of them, otherwise you are simply not implementing the interface. The interface claims that it accepts them all. You can return StringData because you may return anything that qualifies as a Data<String>, and StringData does.

Comment: @kumesana that looks like an answer to me.

Comment: yea but it is in comment so I can not accept it :P

Comment: Lets say you have `class Parent { void eat(Fruit t){..} }` and `class Child extends Parent { @override void eat (Apple a){..} }`. Because `Child extends Parent` we can write `Parent p = new Child();`. But because `p` is of type `Parent` which should support `eat(Fruit)` we should be able to safely invoke `p.eat(new Banana())` (where `Banana` is subtype of `Fruit` but not `subtype of Apple`). So what should happen here? Code of which method should be invoked? Overriding limited acceptable arguments to Apples, but Parent promised to handle all kinds of Fruits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public interface Testicek<A extends Serializable> {

    public abstract Data<A> test(Data<A> bla);

}
```

Java allows [*covariant return types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#d5e14327), which means that implementations of an interface can return more specific types than the parent interface, because those more-specific types are still instances of less-specific types, and thus they meet the contract of the interface.

However, you can't use more specific parameter types, because the contract of the interface says that it must accept *any* instance of that type.

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) tells us that subclasses have to accept parameters that are no more restrictive, and must return values that are no more general.

Java doesn't allow you to use "less restrictive" parameter types, because of [the way it resolves methods to invoke at compile time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) (which is already *pretty* complicated). This is unnecessarily restrictive from a theoretical point of view, but simpler from a practical point of view.

In terms of you accepting and returning the same type: declare another type variable in your interface:

```
public interface Testicek<A extends Serializable, D extends Data<A>> {

    public abstract D test(D bla);

}
```

Then your implementation can be:

```
public class TesticekImpl implements Testicek<String, StringData> {
    @Override
    public StringData test(StringData bla) {
        return null;
    }
}
```